# Vue: CSS modules not applying or showing with SCSS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

if i use CSS modules,ex: `class="$style.headerNew"` , when my class is nested inside another class in the CSS like:

```
#container {
  .headerNew {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

the CSS is not applied but if I move it outside, it works as follows:

```
#container {

}
.headerNew {
  background: blue;
}
```

if I use normal CSS classes or scoped styles, the SCSS works nested...just not for CSS modules syntax

```
<template>
  <div id="container">
    <Header :class="$style.headerNew"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const Header = () => import('./components/Header.vue');

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Header
  }
}
</script>

<style module lang="scss">
#container {
  .headerNew {
    background: blue;
  }
}

</style>
```

**package.json**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "sass": "^1.32.8",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },
```

Comment: Why are you using `:class="$style.headerNew"`? Have you tried just using `<Header class="headerNew" />`?

Comment: @RodrigoMata I am trying to use CSS Modules rather than pure CSS.... https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html

Comment: Ah gotcha. This is probably out of the scope of the question, but have you tried using [scoped CSS](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html) for Vue instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should read this [link](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#pre-processors) it's how to install and import SCSS to Vue.
Try to import it in `main.js` file.

Here is [link](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass) for using pre-processors.

And also check if version of sass and Vue you are using are compatible... I met an issue that some versions are not compatible with each other.

Comment: the SCSS is working fine if I use the SCSS styles without `module`